# Matching chained method calls with structural search

Tags: intellij-idea, fluent, structural-search

I try to match this kind of method calls of some fluent API. There can be an arbitrary number of method calls (at least 2 calls, but no upper limit). The whole expression should be matched. Actually, the goal is to find chained method calls in a fluent api which omit `doIt()`, as in this case the fluent API does nothing.

```
FooClass.some("fluent")
        .api()
        .bar(()->"somelambda")
        .doIt();
```

I tried something like

```
FooClass.$a$($b$)
```

and use different "occurence counts" like `0,∞` for `$a$`, and `0,1` for `$b$`, but this still only matches `FooClass.some("fluent")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the fluent api methods return an instance of `FooClass`, the following should work.
Start with the existing template *method calls* and add a semicolon to search for statements:

`$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$);`

Click Edit variables:

1. set `Expression type` of *Instance* to `FooClass`
2. set `Text/Regexp` of *MethodCall* to `doit` and enable `Invert condition`

Comment: The API methods don't return instances of `FooClass`, but it seems it is still possible to use an expression type matching multiple classes `(FooClass|BarClass)` as I will post in an answer

Answer (score 2):

A solution based on the answer of Bas Leijdekkers, if anyone has a similar problem.

Using these class definitions for the example:

```
static class FooClass{

    static BarClass bar(){
       return new BarClass();
    }
}

static class BarClass{

     Bar2Class bar2(){
        return new Bar2Class();
    }

    BarClass self(){return this;}
}

static class Bar2Class{

    FinalClass bar3(){
        return new FinalClass();
    }
    Bar2Class self(){return this;}
}

static class FinalClass{
    void doIt(){
        System.out.println("bar2");
    }
    FinalClass doSomethingElse(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

I ended up with two-three expressions:

1. Matching the static method `FooClass.bar()`. No inverted `doIt`condition needed

   `FooClass.$MethodCall$($Parameter$);`
2. Matching the intermediate classes FooClass,BarClass. No inverted `doIt`condition needed

   `$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$);`

   Expression type of the instance is `(FooClass|BarClass)`
3. Matching the classes `Bar2Class`, `FinalClass`. The difference is here that it is possible to make a valid expression by adding `doIt()` to the expression. This probably only works when there is only one final call.

   `$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$);`

   Expression type of the instance is `(Bar2Class|FinalClass)`
    Here using the inverted constraint on the method call `doIt`

   The replacement template is
   `$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$).doIt();`

These structural search pattern can then also be used as inspections in IntelliJ.

Test cases:

```
    FooClass.bar().bar2();

    FooClass.bar();

    FooClass.bar().self().self().bar2();

    FooClass.bar().bar2().bar3(); // do it can be added

    FooClass.bar().bar2();

    FooClass.bar().self().bar2();

    FooClass.bar().bar2().bar3().doSomethingElse(); // do it can be added


    FooClass.bar().bar2().self().bar3().doSomethingElse(); // do it can be added

    FooClass.bar().bar2().bar3().doSomethingElse().doIt(); // all but this are invalid and found by the inspections
```